# avoid specifying redundant template parameters which contain templated function pointer

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

Suppose we have this code:

```
template <class T, void (*u)(T&)>
void Foo()
{
   // store the function u internally . . .
}
```

There are reasons to do something like this and I won't attempt to go into them. However, is there any way to avoid having to specify type `T` when calling `Foo()`? For example, to compile, one normally needs:

```
Foo<int, MyIntFunction>();
```

But if this `int` can be deduced from the function pointer, is this possible:

```
Foo<MyIntFunction>();
```

**EDIT** I'm aware of the solution to pass the actual function pointer in as a function parameter, however this is not desired here as it has some perf drawbacks in intensive loop.

Comment: The feature you are looking for is [N3601 Implicit template parameters](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3601.html), which is not yet available. *"The goal is to be able to replace a template declaration like template<typename T, T t> struct C; with another declaration so that we can instantatiate the template like C<&X::f> instead of having to say C<decltype(&X::f), &X::f>."*

Comment: thanks Piotr, your link is the most relevant info so far. Do you know whether it's going to be included in C++ 14?

Comment: definitely not in C++14, hopefully in C++1z (C++17)

Comment: Do you have timings to prove that passing a function pointer is a performance bottleneck? It sounds unlikely to me.

Answer (score 3):

In this example u is not a function pointer, it's a type (the signature of a function pointer). If you want to store a function pointer you need to pass it.

```
template<class T, class F = void(*)(T&)>
void Foo(F f)
{
  // store the function pointer f here
}
```

called like so:

```
struct SomeType {};
void bar(SomeType& x);

Foo(&bar);
```

Is this what you mean to do?

Comment: Or simply `template <typename T> void Foo(void (*)(T&)) { /*...*/ }`

Comment: thanks Richard. Your suggestion works but is not what I was looking for (see my edit). Ideally we would not change anything with the definition of Foo.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: I don't think it is possible.

Long one.. When calling a template function, you cannot omit the first parameter and specify the second: the compiler would try to match your `MyIntFunction` to the template parameter `T`. Generally, you can specify the first, but omit the second if the compiler can infer the second template parameter. In this case, this is not an option however, because you want to specify the second parameter explicitly.

The second template parameter has a dependency (`T`) on the first template parameter. Therefore, reversing the order of the template parameters is also not an option.

Your best bet would be to define it in a way similar to what Richard suggested:

```
template<class T>
void Foo(T f)
{
   int a(1);
   f(a); // this forces f to be a function taking an int as parameter
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a dirty implementation which basically does what the OP was asking for. It depends on too many assumptions, but could be at least something to discuss. The idea is to specify in advance all possible types which can serve as function argument, and then deduce this type.

```
#include<iostream>

template<typename T>
struct TD; //type display

template<typename FunctionType, typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct ArgumentDeduction
{
    typedef typename std::conditional<std::is_same<void, typename std::result_of<FunctionType(T)>::type>::value
                                     , T
                                     , typename ArgumentDeduction<FunctionType, Ts ...>::type
                                     >::type type;
};

template<typename FunctionType, typename T>
struct ArgumentDeduction<FunctionType, T>
{
    typedef typename std::conditional<std::is_same<void, typename std::result_of<FunctionType(T)>::type>::value
                                     , T
                                     , void
                                     >::type type;    
};


template<typename FunctionType
       , typename T = typename ArgumentDeduction<FunctionType, int, double>::type >
void foo()
{
    TD<T>();
}

struct AvoidConversion
{
    struct DummyType{};
    template<typename T> DummyType operator()(T x) { return DummyType(); }    
};

struct Bar : public AvoidConversion
{
    using AvoidConversion::operator();

    void operator()(int x);
    //void operator()(double x);   //try also this
};

int main()
{
    foo<Bar>();  //calls the foo<Bar,int> version    
}
```

One main assumption here is the form of the `Bar` functor, which in principle accepts any type, but has a relevant implementation of type `void` only for the single allowed type.

Again, I don't think this is rather useful, but I guess this comes closest to the OP's question up to now.

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/05bddd0f3ef0df00)

---

**EDIT:** Otherwise, i.e. without `AvoidConversion` in the code above, the compiler will perform an implicit conversion and the argument deduction gives `true` for all types which are convertible into each other (such that, e.g., `int` is deduced when there is only a function taking double).

If someone sees a way to avoid this ugly `AvoidConversion` hack and deduce the parameter type somehow more elegant, I would be interested in seeing that.