# C++ how to build a class `variable_type_of` which complements `std::result_of`?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-traits

This is a follow-up question to an answer I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27114325/2412846). It contains a first clumsy trial of mine to approach something as a struct `variable_type_of` would produce. My question is: *how to turn this into a serious implementation?*

For example, consider the following class `A`:

```
struct B{};

struct A
{
    void operator()(int) const { /* do something */}
    void operator()(B const&) const { /* do something */}
    double operator()(double, double) const { /* do something */}
};
```

Since C++11 it is easy to obtain the return type given a function signature via `std::result_of<A(int)>::type`,say (and before C++11 it's easy as well using boost::mpl).

Here I'm asking for the opposite and probally much more sophisticated feature, namely for a class `variable_type_of`. Applied to class A its member `type` could be evaluated as follows (--this is just a first suggestion):

```
variable_type_of<A>::type  ==  std::tuple<int, B const&, std::tuple<double,double> >;
```

Is there a way to do it in C++11? Can it be made "nice" (--meaning not that unusable as [my own trial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27114325/2412846))?

Comment: Why? What is your underlying goal? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: This is not possible in C++11, you need some form of reflection or compiler support. Take a look at [std::experimental::invocation_traits](https://rawgit.com/cplusplus/fundamentals-ts/v1/fundamentals-ts.html#meta.trans.other) (which requires compiler support to implement)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: at the moment just couriosity, nothing more (the question was raised in the linked thread, at least if I understood it correctly). But I don't think its hard to construcct a non-exotic application for this. Further and more generally, I'd find it also more consistent with the existence of `std::result_of` if such were available in the standard library.

Comment: @davidhigh I think your answer there is just a workaround which would require the OP there to re-work all functions into functors. That may be acceptable, or it may not be, but either way, it wasn't the question that was asked. Anyway, for your question here, if it's not hard to construct a non-exotic application for this, I welcome you to do so. Everything I can think of already has a simpler solution that does not need what you're asking for. That may be a lack of imagination on my part, or it may be that there is actually little need for this.

Comment: @hvd: yes, as said above it's a completely unusable workaround. One has to use functors which disallow conversion and explicitly state all possible types. But, as a first non-exotic application, if such a generic feature would be available, one could easily answer the linked question. Next, one could easily implement things such as "if a function taking parameter-type-1 is available, call it, otherwise call the function with parameter-type-2". This can be solved differently and such code could also be questioned for its design, but still I think it isn't that far away from everyday needs.

Comment: @hvd: the potential need for this is maybe also confirmed by the `std::experimental` implementation (which I haven't looked at yet, though). Ok, the fact that it's not available yet renders it to be not *that strong* :)

Comment: @JonathanWakely: could you explain why exactly this requires compiler support? Does `std::result_of` also requires special support (beside general C++11 support)? If not, why can't the same be made with a variable type instead of a return type?

Comment: @davidhigh, no, `result_of` needs no magic. To use `result_of` you specify the type of the functor and the types of the arguments, so getting the result type just means constructing an expression that involves all those types and using `decltype` to ask the compiler what the result is: `decltype(std::declval<F&>()(std::declval<Args>()...))` (plus some partial specializations to handle pointers-to-member). [continued...]

Comment: ... But given a functor `A` there's no way to identify the argument types that it can accept, because it would involve trying every possible combination of every possible C++ type to see if it accepts it, which is an unbounded set. Your trial assumes a single argument of type `int` or `double`. You cannot extend that to functions taking arbitrary numbers of arguments of arbitrary types. And what if the functor has a `template<typename T> void operator()(T)` function template, what is its parameter type?

Comment: Also, don't you mean `parameter_type_of` or `argument_type_of`, not `variable_type_of`? The question title is  pretty confusing and doesn't describe the problem well